# pandoc commands in google colab

Tags: latex, markdown, jupyter, pandoc, google-colaboratory

I am new to the markdown. I want to write a report with python code and I would like to add title, author and date. I tried to use this code

```
---
title: My Title
author: My author
---
```

But this is not working. Can anyone suggest how to sort this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just by the syntax, it should be the right markdown format and pandoc should be able to format it. Try using this code:

```py
import pypandoc

mytext = """
---
title: My Title
author: My author
--- """

pypandoc.convert_text(mytext,'pdf',format='markdown',
                               outputfile="output.pdf",
                               extra_args=['--pdf-engine','pdflatex'])
```

It should give you output.pdf that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I tried it. Here is the [notebook file](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1-KBhkqHMSFs7ggp8X4B1wp2Y-p588Rvz)